# I tried to restore a dmg image onto an external drive and got 'Recovery partition restores can only be done on GPT partitions'

Tags: macos, restore, partition

I already formatted the external drive into smaller 200GB partitions with Extended Journal on my Mac Yosemite 10.10.4. Don't know what it is complaining about.

Answer (score 0):

Found out that before i split the big external drive into smaller partitions, i need to erase format it as Extended first. The way i set it up is each smaller partition is Mac OS Extended but the main drive is still MSDOS FAT.